# How to hide validation message which fires when form is edited in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on MVC framework. In the Home-Page I have multiple forms, which is shown and hidden using `data-ng-show data-ng-hide`.

The problem is when I hide the form after filling some inputs fields, validation message fires when I reopen the form. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you could show/hide the validation messages using similar logic that you already are using to show/hide things in the UI?

Comment: These message are shown only when form validation error occurs. And this done with ng-hide and show. The problem is when i close the form using ng-hide, after filling some fields, form $dirty validation fires. Since all the fields are mandatory.

Comment: A simple boolean variable that you set to true when the ng-submit/ng-click/whatever function is called would solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **$scope.formName.$setPristine()** on reopen function